# Programmatically adding excel data labels in a bar chart

Tags: excel, charts, progress-4gl

I try to add a bar chart to an excel file. 
I am using ABL (4GL) to do this:

```
ASSIGN
vchChart = chExcelApplication:Charts:Add()
vchChart:ChartType = 57
vchChart:HasTitle = FALSE.

vchChart:SetSourceData(chWorkSheet2:Range("B1:B" + STRING(iCounter - 1))).
vchChart:ApplyDataLabels(5).
vchChart:Location(2, "Tabelle1":U).
```

This creates a bar chart, but the labels for the data are 1,2,3,4,...
I would like to use a range of fields in excel to display as the labels for the chart bars.

[image]

This should look something like this:

[image]

If I were to do this manually I would use the following in Excel:
[image]

How can I add those labels programmatically?
That means I would like to use a certain range of cells for the labels as indicated in this pseudy code:

```
SetLabels(chWorkSheet2:Range("A1:A" + STRING(iCounter - 1))).
```

Comment: You cannot create a column with CONCATENATE( ... ) and use them on the BarChar ?

Comment: Can you give me more details about how you would do that?

Comment: The starting value are in the cells A1:A13 in the cells B1:B13 you put a formula =CONCATENATE("Label ";A1)  In label you put what you want. For example C1 where you can put every value different ... Eventually By code you change the value of C1...

Comment: Perhaps this post in the Progress Knowledgebase can help you? http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P72109?q=excel+chart&l=en_US&fs=Search&pn=1

Answer (score 0):

If these labels are in a worksheet range, then something like this (this is VBA; make its syntax compatible with the program you're using):

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = chWorkSheet2.Range("B1:B" + STRING(iCounter - 1))